# windows mobile hide sip (keypad) in internet explorer without regedit (only html,js)

Tags: javascript, windows, mobile, keypad

(windows mobile ce, internet explorer) when users perform focus into a textfield, the keypad(sip) is automatically opened, which is not desired. the users  do not need any keypad because the device has already a big keypad and they do not want to see the virtual keypad, becuase it consumes lots of space on the small screen.

i can not modify registry.

when i add this line to the onfocus,

```
 document.activeElement.blur()
```

the keypad gets away, but the focus also gets away and we can not edit the textfield anymore. the desired situation is, we focus to the textfield, it becomes the focus, cursor is blinking but we do not see any keypad.

Is there a way to do this by html+javascript? I could not find any related setting on the device (internet explorer options or device options)

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting

```
Control Panel
Internet Options
Advanced
Browsing
> Disable automatic SIP
```

Although for some reason I can not seem to just select it on screen... But that might be my own usersettings.